# OSX BLE advertising data format

Tags: macos, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm having trouble understanding how OSX formats BLE advertising packet data. In the screenshot below, kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs in the locals window (on the left) has a certain format that I don't understand (for example, ...376A0). In the log window (on the right), they're printed in a recognizable format (for example, 180D). How is the translation done?

More importantly, I don't understand the kCBAdvSDataServiceData format <3a636401 01>. The service data in my peripheral has 1 byte for the length + 2 bytes for the service + 5 bytes of data. How can I translate the service data into something I understand? In my peripheral, the service data uses 0x180D.
[image]

Comment: ...376A0 is the address in memory of the `CBUUID` object - note that the type is `CBUUID *` - A pointer

Comment: Thanks for "pointing" that out :) How do I get the raw UUID to print in the log? It seems to be decoded into "battery", "device information", etc (why isn't battery in quotes in the log?). I'm trying NSlog("%@", uid); to log it, and it doesn't give me the raw UUID. What exactly does "%@" do?

Comment: I found the "data" property gives the raw UUID

Answer (score 0):

Advertising Data is a list of AD structures.

An AD structure contains:

```
- length (1 byte) = total length of Type + Data
- AD Type (1 byte)
- AD Data (length-1 bytes)
```

AD Structures are concatenated to form the Advertising Data.
Same goes for Scan Response Data.

The AD Type is defined by the SIG and has many possible values. As far as I know, iOS/OSX only allows 3 types to be defined by the user: Local Name, Service UUID List, don't know the third one. But there are many more, check the complete list here: https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/assigned-numbers/generic-access-profile

The AD Data and length is specific to each AD Type.

Comment: In the log file, what is the space in the ServiceData value: <3a636401 01>? Shouldn't this just be a contiguous value? The five data bytes are correct: 0x3a, 0x63, 0x64, 0x01, 0x01 but I'm wondering if OSX puts the space to separate groups of 8 bytes when printing using "%@"?

Comment: Also, how do I get the "raw value" from this _NSInlineData? I don't want to rely on saving this as a NSString and getting the byte values from the NSString since OSX may format this differently in some future version and break the code.

Comment: @tosa That space is put out to logically separate the Service Data. I'm not sure what is the format for Heart Rate Service Data in advertising packets, maybe that 01 is the body sensor location? The service data is formatted differently for different services.

Comment: Actually the data is proprietary from my peripheral (I'm hacking into 0x180D to simplify things during test), so the last 0x01 isn't body sensor location but some proprietary data. So it seems like the space is just a formatter that puts a space every 8 characters (if interpreting them as bytes) using "%@" since the raw data (per the data property) shows just 5 bytes.